# How to vertically center an equation in a merged row?

Tags: latex

I have an equation in a multi row cell (aka a merged cell) that should be vertically centered. I do using the following code snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage
{
    multirow,
    longtable,
    array
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*{2}{c|}}\hline
\parbox[c][1cm]{5cm}{Description} & \parbox[c][1cm]{5cm}{Formula}\\\hline
\multirow{3}*
{
    \parbox[c][1cm]{5cm}
    {
        \centering$\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x)\, \textrm{d}x=F(b)-F(a)$
    }
}
            &\parbox[c][1cm]{5cm}{ A } \\\cline{2-2}
            &\parbox[c][1cm]{5cm}{ B } \\\cline{2-2}
            &\parbox[c][1cm]{5cm}{ C } \\\hline
\parbox[c][1cm]{5cm}{D} & \parbox[c][1cm]{5cm}{E}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to make it vertically centered without doing trial and error adjustments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using \multirow for first cell, putting the three rows in a tabular inside second cell can solve the problem. That gives you the freedom of ignoring the height of second cell.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,longtable,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|*{2}{c@{}|@{}}}
\hline
\parbox[c][1cm]{5cm}{Description} 
& \parbox[c][1cm]{5cm}{~~~Formula}\\\hline
$\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x)\,
     \textrm{d}x=F(b)-F(a)$
&\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  \parbox[c][1cm]{5cm}{~~ A } \\\hline
  \parbox[c][1cm]{5cm}{~~ B } \\\hline
  \parbox[c][1cm]{5cm}{~~ C } \\
 \end{tabular}\\\hline
\parbox[c][1cm]{5cm}{D} & \parbox[c][1cm]{5cm}{~~~E}\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've spent some time with it without really solving it. You could of course increase the second argument to `parbox` from 1cm to 3cm since each cell is 1cm high (give or take a few mm). But how to expand the parbox to exactly fill the cell I can't figure out. Not even sure it's possible.

Perhaps you could use

```
\newlength{\threecells}
\settoheight{\threecells}{a tabular of three cells}
```

and then use `\threecells` in your second argument.

Comment: I agree, the problem is that multirow puts you in horizontal mode with no hooks that I know of into the vertical height of the box. Manual fiddling with `\vbox` and `\vskip` seems to be the right thing.

Comment: How can you do \settoheight{\threecells}{a tabular of three cells} ?

Comment: Well, something like `\settoheight{\threecells}{\begin{tabular}{l}a \\ a \\ a\end{tabular}}` but I can't say it worked very well for me. You have custom cells in your tabular, so the three cells won't be as high as your three custom cells. You're probably better off fiddling with `\vspace` and such.